# My code has a simple issue that i cant figure out

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, sorting, parsing

I am setting up a link for my web page to take me to another site.

Ive tried everything i know how to do . my knowledge is limited though. basically when you visit https://beatsbycayde.com/roster/ it should take you to

```html
"https://braytech.org/2/{destinyId}/{characterId}/legend"
```

for some reason it doesnt And I cannot figure out why any help would be greatly appreciated it it instead takes you to

```html
https://braytech.org/2/{destinyId}/fstats/legend
```

I know that i have fstats in there iam trying to us it as an object and call it in the href

```js
// get list of members and populate roster table
var roster = [];
$.when($.ajax({
  url: "https://www.bungie.net/platform/GroupV2/699392/Members/",
  headers: {
    "X-API-Key": "47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
  }
}).success(function(json) {
  if (json.ErrorStatus === 'Success') {
    roster = json.Response.results;
    console.log('Exalted member list:', roster);
  } else {
    alert('Uh oh, looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
    console.log(json);
  }
}).error(function(json) {
  alert('Uh oh, looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
  console.log(json);
}), $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.bungie.net/platform/destiny2/2/profile/4611686018429000034/?components=200',
  headers: {
    'X-API-Key': "47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
  }
}).success(function(res) {
  console.log('PS4 stats:', res);
})).then(function() {
  listMembers(roster);
});

function listMembers(rsp) {
  var list = $('.memberList-list'),
    on = 0,
    sortMembers = function(method) {
      // sort by date joined
      if (method = joined) {
        list.find('.member').sort(function(a, b) {
          return ($(b).data('joined')) < ($(a).data('joined')) ? 1 : -1;
        }).appendTo(list);
      } else if (method = username) {
        list.find('.member').sort(function(a, b) {
          return ($(b).data('username')) < ($(a).data('username')) ? 1 : -1;
        }).appendTo(list);
      }
      list.find('.member.online').prependTo(list);
    };
  for (var i = 0; i < rsp.length; i++) {
    var profile = rsp[i].bungieNetUserInfo,
      member = $('<a></a>');
    // tally up online members
    if (rsp[i].isOnline) {
      on++
    }
    // check for valid profile
    // some users don't have Bungie profiles somehow and it breaks function
    if (typeof profile != 'undefined') {
      // store response data in semantic variables
      var name = rsp[i].destinyUserInfo.displayName,
        joinDate = rsp[i].joinDate,
        joined = joinDate.substring(0, joinDate.indexOf('T')),
        online = rsp[i].isOnline,
        icon = profile.iconPath,
        memberId = profile.membershipId,
        memberType = rsp[i].destinyUserInfo.membershipType,
        destinyId = rsp[i].destinyUserInfo.membershipId,
        rank = rsp[i].memberType;
      // configure D OM node and add to page
      $('#destiny-Id').text(destinyId);
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/" + destinyId + "/",
        headers: {
          "X-API-Key": "47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
        }
      }).done(function(json) {});
      $(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/4611686018429000034/",
          headers: {
            "X-API-Key": "47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
          },
          success: function(data) {
            // Gambit stats
            var fstats = data.Response.data.characters[0].characterBase.characterId;
            // Populate stats
            // pvp
            $('#player-f-stats').text(fstats);
          },
          error: function(data) {
            alert('Uh oh, failed to load player stats! Looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
            console.log('Error loading player stats:', data);
          }
        });
      });
      member.attr({
        'class': 'j-row vertical-center-row member',
        'href': '/player/?bungieId=' + memberId + '&destinyId=' + destinyId + '&joined=' + joined + '&rank=' + rank,
        'title': 'See player profile for ' + name,
        'data-joined': joined.replace(/-/g, ''),
        'data-username': name,
        'data-online': 'false',
        'data-searchable': name,
      }).html('<div class="j-col j-col-1 member-icon"><img src="https://bungie.net/' + icon + '"></div>' + '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-name"><h3>' + name + '</h3></div>' + '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-joined" data-label="Joined">' + joined.replace(/-/g, '/') + '</div>' + '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-status" data-label="Status"><span class="member-online" id="status-' + memberId + '">' + online + '</span></div>' + '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-button"><a class="button outline gold full-width">' + 'View Stats' + '</a></div>' + '<div class="j-col j-col-3 member-button"> + <a href="https://braytech.org/2/' + destinyId + '/' + "fstats" + '/legend">In Depth Stats</a>' + '</a></div>').appendTo(list);
      // indicate online/offline status
      if (String(online) === 'true') {
        $('#status-' + memberId).text('Online').addClass('online').closest('.member').attr('data-online', true).addClass('online');
      } else {
        $('#status-' + memberId).text('Offline').removeClass('online');
      }
      sortMembers(joined); // sort members by join date
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @apnp_apnu. Welcome to SO.  Your code is kind of unreadable at this point. Please tidy it up a bit so we can try to help you.

Comment: i tried tidying it up does that help?

Comment: It's better! But, notice in the `Snippet Editor` there is a button `Tidy` under `Save and insert into post`. Use that as well.

Comment: i just did that as well.

Comment: Thank you. That really helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested links. That breaks your HTML and prevents the `href` you want to be used.

Here you create the wrapper of each member. Which is a link.

```
member.attr({
    'class': 'j-row vertical-center-row member',
    'href': '/player/?bungieId=' + memberId + '&destinyId=' + destinyId + '&joined=' + joined + '&rank=' + rank,
    ...
```

And then you append another link inside of it here:

```
... <a href="https://braytech.org/2/' + destinyId + '/' + "fstats" + '/legend">In Depth Stats</a>' ...
```

So I would suggest that you change the structure of your `member` element. Maybe place the top link in the position of the `View Stats button` and change that button to a `<a>` tag. But then as a consensus the whole `member` element won't be clickable, only the links.

Good luck!